# World time converter under emacs and/or orgmode

Tags: org-mode, time-date

Is there a World time converter under emacs and/or orgmode?

As everything moves online, it occurs more often than before that I want to schedule in orgmode an online event which occurs in some other part of the world, with a time in a distinct time zone (e.g. "9pm in Malaisia" or "9pm in GMT+8"). If the time zone is specified it is a simple mental gymnastic to compute my local time (e.g. from GMT+8 to GMT-3), which I nevertheless would like to delegate to emacs. But when the time zone is not specified, just the location (e.g. "Malaysia"), I usually go to a website, which does break the workflow of capturing an event.

I would like to be able to enter a time coordinate (i.e. date and time) using a variant of `org-time-stamp` which

- takes as an extra parameter the location (e.g. Malaysia) or time zone (e.g. GMT+8) of the event;
- computes the correct time for my own time zone (e.g. GMT-3); and
- copies in the buffer both the active time stamp and an inactive time stamp with the original time and time zone specified.

For instance, programming a 1h video talk at 9pm in Malaysia on the 27th of March would result in the time stamp  `<2021-03-27 Sat 10:00-11:00> ([2021-03-27 Sat 21:00-22:00] in Malaysia, GMT+8)`. I guess I could program (nice lisp exercise, taking care of the potential change of date when an event is close to midnight!), but I am curious to know if such a solution already exists before reinventing the wheel: maybe people scheduling plane flights already had it working in emacs, a simple internet search did not reveal anything.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/ndw/wwtime)?